# Best way to encapsulate that

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The question should be simple, but i'm thinking what the best way to do this is. Simply, there is a User model and a Quest model. A user has one quest. Now, i just want to check whether a user's quest is expired.

I thought that i would have to put expired? as an instance method to quest. Now, i can do something like :

```
current_user.quest.expired?
```

or even create a delegate later, to make it like :

```
current_user.quest_expired?
```

However, there is a nuisance. If the user does not have a quest, this one will return with a nil error. I would not want to have a check beforehand or create a different method for the User model, because i feel that this breaks encapsulation.

How would you do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually done with:

```
delegate :expired?, :to => :quest, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
```

Comment: another great reply, i'm now having trouble selecting the best answer :/

Answer (score 1):

Usually this gets solved this way in Rails:

Define both methods:

```
current_user.quest.expired?
current_user.quest_expired?
```

and define the latter method as:

```
def quest_expired?
  return nil unless quest
  quest.expired?
end
```

And then call the quest_expired? if you can't be sure the user has a quest.

Comment: yeah, i was thinking the of the same actually. Though it's a bit redundant, i can't really find any other better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
current_user.quest.try(:expired?)
```

Comment: great, i did not know of try :)